# How to get transaction information from paypal

Tags: python, paypal

I wrote the following script using the paypal package: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK:

```
import paypalrestsdk
paypalrestsdk.configure({
  "mode": "live", 
  "client_id":  MY ID
  "client_secret": MY SECRET
  })

payment_history = paypalrestsdk.Payment.all({"count": 10})
print("List Payment:")
for payment in payment_history.payments:
    print("  -> Payment[%s]" % (payment.id))
```

This should give me the last 10 transactions.
However it doesn't work.

This is the output:

> List Payment:
>
> ```
> for payment in payment_history.payments: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
> ```

What is the problem?
I understand the error (nothing returned so it's not iteratable) what I don't understand is why it's nothing. What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Interesting question for me as I haven't used paypal since a long ago. As per their documentation. Do they provide a different way to check if the keys (id and secret) are correct without the need of call any other method?

Comment: @HéctorValverdePareja the ID and Secret can not be wrong as I copied them from paypal account. Also, if the keys are wrong it will give a handshack exception (changed them and verified it). Sadly, paypal does not provide much information. They refer here for questions. This is the package code: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK

Comment: And ... what about the mode? Are you developing in 'live' mode instead the 'sandbox'?

Comment: @HéctorValverdePareja  The mode is live as I wrote. I just want the last 10 transactions why do I need sandbox? This is a simple get request...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is due to the fact that the SDK API doesn't return transactions that were not created by the SDK Payment.create().

Payment.all() only list the payments that are created using Payment.create api call.

See https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/3
Solution: [Retrieving all Payment info from PayPal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050232/retrieving-all-payment-info-from-paypal-app/23122397#23122397)